# yii, how to use getAttributeLabel()

Tags: yii, model, checkboxlist

I have a problem on yii model, ive been told to use the `generateAttributeLabel()` on the model, but i tried to use it on the way i thought it would work but it doesnt. This is my code

```
public function generateAttributeLabel($variable = file_get_contents('protected\column.txt'))
{
    return $variable;
}   

public function attributeLabels()
{
        return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'parametro_id' => 'Parametro',
    );
}
```

There are some columns that are being generated automatically and i thought to save their names into a file and its saved as example like `(index, par, tolt, sircer)`. Thats why the `file_get_contents()`, but i get an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'.
```

so i really dont know and i need this to make checkboxlist with the attributes of each column thats going to be saved as y or n, if someone could tell me how to use this with checkboxlist would be appretiated.

the content file is this

```
lololo,
```

for now it has 1 element, but will be adding more each time a column is created

Comment: Paste the contents of the txt file pls.

Comment: content of the file pasted

Comment: You can't use a function return value in parameters declaration of a function

Comment: well. im still new programmer, how would i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a function return value as a default value in a function declaration, you will need to set that up in the function itself

```
public function generateAttributeLabel($variable = null){
    if($variable){
        $variable = file_get_contents($variable);
    }

    return $variable;
}
```

Comment: well. that made the work, thanks, now its just giving me an error with the checkboxlist which i will try fix, thanks

Comment: @nosthertus you're always welcome. I'm just going to edit the answer and set `$variable` inside `file_get_contents` just so that it doesn't look silly. Good luck with your other errors! `:P`